# Show Tooltip on disabled control inside a GroupBox

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I'm using the following code to show a tooltip on a disabled CheckBox which is placed inside a GroupBox.
Howeven the tooltip displays when i move the mouse over the CheckBox *only if i first click outside the GroupBox* and then i drag the mouse arrow over the CheckBox.

It's like if the GroupBox is covering the main panel of the dialog and it's not triggering the event.

But GroupBox has no MouseMove event, so i'm wondering how to fix this.

```
delegate void SetToolTipDelegate(ToolTip^ tooltip, Control^ control, String^ text);
void SetToolTip(ToolTip^ tooltip, Control^ control, String^ text)
{
    if (control->InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetToolTipDelegate^ d = gcnew SetToolTipDelegate(this, &MyForm::SetToolTip);
        this->Invoke(d, gcnew cli::array<Object^> { tooltip, control, text });
    }
    else
    {
        tooltip->SetToolTip(control, text);
    }
}

bool isShown;

System::Void MyForm_MouseMove(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e) {
    System::Drawing::Point p = this->checkBox1->Location;
    System::Drawing::Point g = this->groupBox1->Location;
    System::Drawing::Rectangle r = this->checkBox1->ClientRectangle;
    if ((e->X >= (p.X + g.X)) && (e->X <= (p.X + g.X + r.Width)) && (e->Y >= (p.Y + g.Y)) && (e->Y <= (p.Y + g.Y + r.Height)))
    {
        if (!isShown) {
            SetToolTip(this->toolTip1, this->checkBox1, "Here my tooltip text...");
            this->toolTip1->Show("Here my tooltip text...", this->checkBox1, r.Width / 2, r.Height / 2);
            isShown = TRUE;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        this->toolTip1->Hide(this->checkBox1);
        isShown = FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: The MouseMove event is fired on the control with the focus.  That will never be the form, it will be a child control of the form.  Otherwise the reason that "click outside the groupbox" seems to be the workaround.  The probable sane way to get ahead is to assume that the user will not be interested in knowing how a control works that he can't use anyway.  You can still use the GroupBox.MouseMove event, as long as the FlatStyle property isn't "System".

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the advice, just added answer for anyone else looking for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this (using the same callback for the Form and the GroupBox) did the trick:

```
this->groupBox1->MouseMove += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventHandler(this, &MyForm::MyForm_MouseMove);
```